# Sprockets::FileNotFound jquery.atwho

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I'm trying to add [jquery-atwho-rails](https://github.com/ichord/jquery-atwho-rails) to my app, which is a rails gem for [at.js](https://github.com/ichord/At.js), I've followed the instructions, ran `bundle install`, added the required code to `application.js` and `application.css`, stop and restarted the server, but I always keep getting this error:

`couldn't find file 'jquery.atwho'`

I can't figure out how to fix this error, can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'acts_as_follower', '~> 0.1.1'
gem 'js-routes'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.4.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.8.0'
gem 'rinku'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'progress_bar'
gem 'swf_fu', '~> 2.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'auto_html'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'randumb'
gem 'figaro'
gem "auto_strip_attributes", "~> 2.0"
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "wysiwyg-rails"
gem 'rails_engine_decorators'
gem 'jquery-atwho-rails'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'shoulda'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'sunspot_solr'
    gem 'debugger'
end 

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end 

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require js-routes
//= require swf_fu
//= require soundmanager2-nodebug
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require private_pub
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/lists.min.js
//= require plugins/char_counter.min.js
//= require plugins/fullscreen.min.js
//= require jquery.atwho
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css**

```
*= require_self
*= require redactor-rails
*= require froala_editor.min.css
*= require froala_style.min.css
*= require font-awesome
*= require jquery.atwho
*= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a problem with the gem but I ended up uninstalling it and adding `jquery.atwho.js`, `jquery.atwho.css`, and `caret.js` directly to my assets and everything started working as it should.